Try/Catch function inconsistency when "batching" using ScriptProperties
So, this post is a continuation of a post I made 10 months ago. I'll reference it multiple times in this one, but here is the link to it to go back to: Import of a Large Quantity of API Data
To start, I have been working on a database that pulls from thousands of API/JSON links to create data. After many attempts to do it individually caused the code to error out, time out, or outright fail. I made a post looking for an answer, and that is what lead me to trying to use "batching". Here is the code that was provided, and with a few minor tweaks to fit the data, not to the "batching" part, it worked:
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function dataImport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import1");
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data1");
  var reqs = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [url]) => {
    if (url) {
      ar.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  //Storage of current data
  var bucket = [];
  var batchSize = 200;
  var batches = batchArray(reqs, batchSize);
  var startingBatch = scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber"));
  var processedBatches = scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"));

  console.log(`Total: ${reqs.length}.\n${batches.length} batches.`)

  if (processedBatches >= (batches.length - 1)) {
    console.log('All data has been processed already.');
  } else {
    //Start from the very last batch that stopped that needs to be processed.
    for (let i = startingBatch; i < batches.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Processing batch index #${parseInt(i)}`);
      try {
        var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(batches[i]);
        bucket.push(responses);
        //Remove previous batch index number
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("processedBatches");
        //Store latest sucessful batch index number
        scriptProperties.setProperty("processedBatches", parseInt(i));
      }
      //Catch the last batch index number where it stopped due to URL fetch exception
      catch (e) {
        //Remove the old batch number to be replaced with new batch number.
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("batchNumber");
        //Remember the last batch that encountered and error to be processed again in the next call.
        scriptProperties.setProperty("batchNumber", parseInt(i));
        console.log(`Batch index #${parseInt(i)} stopped`);
        break;
      }
    }

    const initialRes = [].concat.apply([], bucket);

    var temp = initialRes.reduce((ar, r) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position: { abbreviation }, team: { $ref }, birthPlace: { city }, birthPlace: { state, country }, experience: { years, displayValue }, jersey, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
        ar.push([id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, abbreviation, $ref, city, state, country, years, displayValue, jersey, active]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    var res = [...temp];

    //Add table headers
    exportSheet.getLastRow() == 0 && exportSheet.appendRow(['IDs', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Display Name', 'Short Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Position', 'Team URL', 'City', 'State', 'Country', 'Years', 'Class', 'jersey', 'Active']);

    //Add table data
    var result = () => {
      return temp.length != 0 && exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
    result() && console.log(`Processed: ${res.length}.`);
  }
}

//Function to chunk the request data based on batch sizes
function batchArray(arr, batchSize) {
  var batches = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
    batches.push(arr.slice(i, i + batchSize));
  }

  return batches;
}

//Optional function to check the latest processed batch
function checkBatch() {
 console.log(`${parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"))+1} batches have been processed.`);
}

This code is supposed to process then apply each batch individually to the "Import Data" sheet. As I run through the code multiple times, it would increase both the batchNumber and processedBatches ScriptProperties. I would add a trigger into Apps Script that would run the code every minute as it works through all the batches. By saving the properties, the goal is to essentially save the progress of working through the batches to avoid the code timing out. When it was working, it would take around 10-15 seconds each time I would run through the code, and then the per minute trigger would get all the batches applied. The answer in the post goes into greater detail on how it is supposed to work, including a GIF demo, so if you would like detail on that, it explains it better than I can!
Fast forward to the present, and I was looking to update my data with the latest information, and attempted to use the same code I had before. To my dismay, the "batching" that had previously worked was not functioning correctly. It is a bit hard to describe in any other way that inconsistent as it has done multiple different things without me even making any real changes to the code. Sometimes, it will get stuck in a processing loop, where it will keep going through the "try" part of the try/catch loop, listing batch after batch as "processing", but not actually applying the data. The processing would keep going until the code itself would timeout, and would just update the processedBatches property, but not the batchNumber property. This is the option I have seen most frequently. Other times I have seen it process whatever batch it is on, then just stop, not putting any data in after only running once. Then in rare instances it will put a batch in the code, but I haven't been able to get it to do so twice in a row. Usually, when one of the batches does go in the sheet, the next time I run it, I'll be stuck in a processing loop again. Generally, unless a previous attempt was successful, I have been trying multiple things, including setting both properties to zero and removing the properties in order to try and reset the code, but neither has worked to yield successful results. Also, for additional reference, when the code is running right, I haven't needed to manually adjust the properties until all the batches have been applied, then I would reset it, but haven't got anywhere close in this current attempt.
I'm not sure exactly where to go to try and fix this. I already felt lost when trying to put it together, now I have no clue why it stopped working. I did go in and put extra console.log(s) in the code to try and find where the error may be occurring, and that is where I found that the "catch" wasn't consistently processing.
For reference, here is the most current version of the code that I have been working with, and to show that most of the internals I do not believe have been altered. In fact, even went back in and re-pasted the "batching" sections into the code to try and get it to work:
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function dataImport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base JSON Import");
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Import Data");
  var reqs = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [url]) => {
    if (url) {
      ar.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  //Storage of current data
  var bucket = [];
  var batchSize = 200;
  var batches = batchArray(reqs, batchSize);
  var startingBatch = scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("batchNumber"));
  var processedBatches = scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"));

  console.log(`Total: ${reqs.length}.\n${batches.length} batches.`)

  if (processedBatches >= (batches.length - 1)) {
    console.log('All data has been processed already.');
  } else {
    //Start from the very last batch that stopped that needs to be processed.
    for (let i = startingBatch; i < batches.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Processing batch index #${parseInt(i)}`);
      try {
        var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(batches[i]);
        bucket.push(responses);
        console.log(`Fetched batches, pushed responses`);
        //Remove previous batch index number
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("processedBatches");
        console.log(`Removed previous batch index number`);
        //Store latest sucessful batch index number
        scriptProperties.setProperty("processedBatches", parseInt(i));
        console.log(`Stored latest succcessful batch index number`);
      }
      //Catch the last batch index number where it stopped due to URL fetch exception
      catch (e) {
        console.log(`Catching the last batch index number`);
        //Remove the old batch number to be replaced with new batch number.
        scriptProperties.deleteProperty("batchNumber");
        console.log(`Removed old batch number`);
        //Remember the last batch that encountered and error to be processed again in the next call.
        scriptProperties.setProperty("batchNumber", parseInt(i));
        console.log(`Remember the last batch number`);
        console.log(`Batch index #${parseInt(i)} stopped`);
        break;
      }
    }

    const initialRes = [].concat.apply([], bucket);

    var temp = initialRes.reduce((ar, r) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position, dateOfBirth, hand, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace, experience, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
          var { abbreviation = null } = position || {};
          var { displayValue = null } = hand || {};
          var { city = null, state = null, country = null } = birthPlace || {};
          var { years = null } = experience || {};
        ar.push([id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, abbreviation, dateOfBirth, displayValue, jersey, debutYear, city, state, country, years, active]);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    var res = [...temp];

    //Add table headers
    exportSheet.getLastRow() == 0 && exportSheet.appendRow(['IDs', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Display Name', 'Short Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Position', 'DOB', 'Hand', 'Jersey', 'Debut Year', 'City', 'State', 'Country', 'Years', 'Active']);

    //Add table data
    var result = () => {
      return temp.length != 0 && exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
    result() && console.log(`Processed: ${res.length}.`);
  }
}

//Function to chunk the request data based on batch sizes
function batchArray(arr, batchSize) {
  var batches = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
    batches.push(arr.slice(i, i + batchSize));
  }

  return batches;
}

//Optional function to check the latest processed batch
function checkBatch() {
 console.log(`${parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("processedBatches"))+1} batches have been processed.`);
}

In my searches, I already hadn't found great examples of the importation of API links, but I still haven't found much of anything that tackles this inconsistency when pairing "batching" with try/catch. So I now come here to ask for help. I have attached a test sheet if it makes it easier to find an issue, and I appreciate any help I can get! Also, if any more details are needed or desired, please let me know.
Test Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yb-AeTTv7Z5pJNsc13s90bmT3uIOHSovswVzLwEQVkM/edit?usp=sharing


How long does the script take to run  all batches? 2. If you revert back the code to the version that initially worked, does the same error occur? 3. Use Stackdriver logging 4.  listing batch after batch as "processing", but not actually applying the data  Setting the data comes after the loop.. the code doesn't handle r.getResponseCode() !== 200. Maybe all responses were not 200 and therefore setValues failed? Log temp.length. 5. Don't delete property,  just update it.


@TheMaster 1. So what I was generally doing was setting up a trigger that would go every minute when the code was working. Usually takes about an hour to get through all the batches using that, but about 10-15 seconds per run of the code. 2. I tried to mention this in the post, but I did go back in and revert the batch section that has been having issues to the original code and that didn't actually make any changes, but nevertheless still did not work. 3. I can look into that more, but not sure how much it would help in this instance, though. (1/2)

@TheMaster 4. Maybe, though this version of the code was already made to be able to skip any entries that would cause an error, whether though this one or my code that imports the JSONs. A response code may not be a bad idea, but feels weird if it was suddenly an issue. 5. I have tried it both with removing the properties and resetting them to zero. Haven't had luck doing it either way. (2/2)

FWIW: Maybe all responses were not 200 1) Based on my testing, the total number of entries posted to the "Import data" sheet at any time is a multiple of 200. 2) I had a timeout; "Processing batch" 13 to 30; timeout occurred during processing of batch 31; no "Processed" value, no update to "Import Data". When I ran the script afterwards, it timed out again (start= Batch 13, end=Batch 30). It's late at night in Sydney, so traffic might be light - what is in the script to stop it processing before a timeout?

@Tedinoz From what I can tell, there isn't anything in the code to stop it from timing out, but in theory, it shouldn't get to the point where it has to. What it is supposed to do is get to the point where the batchNumber and processedBatches are working in sync, going one at a time, and stopping after every applied batch. I'll add some clarification to the original post, but the fact that the batches aren't applying is causing the processing to either error out or continue instead of applying batch by batch and using a trigger to avoid it timing out.

untested whatif... use a loop and set a limit of the number of transactions (say 10 URLs??) to process before updating the spreadsheet and session values. I imagine that this sounds like a statement of the obvious, but I think that something like this is a missing link in the script. Actually, I'm just re-reading the referenced answer and it proposes processing each batch AND then appending the data to the Data1 sheet. This is along the lines that I suggested above.

You have a script for importing data 12,000+ URLs; the script uses a sophisticated batching method but there is no mechanism to avoid a timeout error.
Consider this answer; it is very similar to the OP's code but there are a couple of key differences:

a single Script Property: lastBatchNumProcessed
two script variables:

batchesPerSession - limit the number of batches to process per execution, and
batchCounter - to count the batches processed


TRY code includes a new line to test for the number of batches processed.

if (batchCounter == batchesPerSession){
break if true, continue processing if false.


CATCH code doesn't change the Script property; the code is simplified
batchArray() is unchanged


var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function dataImport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base JSON Import");
  var exportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ImportData");

  var reqs = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [url]) => {
    if (url) {
      ar.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  //Storage of current data
  var bucket = [];
  var batchSize = 200;
  var batches = batchArray(reqs, batchSize);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: FYI-Number of records = "+reqs.length+", batch size = "+batchSize+", so target number of row in batches = "+batches.length)

  // set a limit of batches to process to avoid timeout
  var batchesPerSession = 10
  var batchCounter = 0
     
  // get session variable(s)
  var lastBatchNumProcessed = scriptProperties.getProperty("lastBatchNumProcessed") == null ? 0 : parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty("lastBatchNumProcessed"));
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Last batch number processed =  = "+lastBatchNumProcessed)


  // test whether there is any processing required.
  if (lastBatchNumProcessed >= (batches.length)) {
    Logger.log('DEBUG: All data has been processed already.');
  } else 
  {
    //Start from the last batch that was processed.
    for (let i = lastBatchNumProcessed; i < batches.length; i++) {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", batch#"+(+i+1)+", rows in batch = "+batches[i].length)

      try {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: get responses using urlFetchApp")
        var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(batches[i]);
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: push the responses into the bucket")
        bucket.push(responses);
        Logger.log("DEBUG: Fetched responses for i="+i+" batch#"+parseInt(i+1)+" pushed responses onto bucket, number of values in the bucket = "+bucket.length)
        
        //Update LastBatchNumProcessed
        scriptProperties.setProperty("lastBatchNumProcessed", parseInt((+i+1)));
        // Logger.log(DEBUG: `Updated latest succcessful batch number = `+scriptProperties.getProperty("lastBatchNumProcessed"));

        // count the batchses processed and stop processing when the limt is reached
        batchCounter = batchCounter+1
        if (batchCounter == batchesPerSession){
          // enough batches have been processed
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Batches processed this session = limit of "+batchesPerSession)
          break
        }
        else{
          // display number of batches processed.
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Batches processed this session = "+batchCounter)
        }

      }
      //Catch the last batch index number where it stopped due to URL fetch exception
      catch (e) {
        Logger.log(`DEBUG: Catching error`);
        Logger.log(`DEBUG: Catch: Batch index #${parseInt(i)} stopped`);
        break;
      }

    }
     
    // test whether any batches were processed this session
    if (batchCounter !=0){

      var ejbInitialRes = [].concat.apply([], bucket);
      //Logger.log("i:"+i+", the length of initial Res = "+ejbInitialRes.length)

      var temp = ejbInitialRes.reduce((ar, r) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var { id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, position, dateOfBirth, hand, jersey, debutYear, birthPlace, experience, active } = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
      var { abbreviation = null } = position || {};
      var { displayValue = null } = hand || {};
      var { city = null, state = null, country = null } = birthPlace || {};
      var { years = null } = experience || {};
      ar.push([id, firstName, lastName, fullName, displayName, shortName, weight, height, abbreviation, dateOfBirth, displayValue, jersey, debutYear, city, state, country, years, active]);
      }
      return ar;
      }, []); 
      var res = [...temp];

      //Add table headers
      exportSheet.getLastRow() == 0 && exportSheet.appendRow(['IDs', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Display Name', 'Short Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Position', 'DOB', 'Hand', 'Jersey', 'Debut Year', 'City', 'State', 'Country', 'Years', 'Active']);
      Logger.log("DEBUG: target range = "+exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).getA1Notation()+", Number of rows = "+res.length+", number of columns = "+res[0].length)
      
      //Add table data
      var result = () => {
      return temp.length != 0 && exportSheet.getRange(exportSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
      }
      result() && Logger.log(`DEBUG: number of records processed: ${res.length}.`); // append data and display message
    }
    else{
      // there are no transaction to process
      Logger.log("DEBUG: No Batches processed.")
    }
    
  } // end if else
}

//Function to chunk the request data based on batch sizes
function batchArray(arr, batchSize) {
  var batches = [];
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: batchArray: data size = "+arr.length+", batch size = "+batchSize)


  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: batchArray: i:"+i+", batch size = "+arr.slice(i, i + batchSize).length)
    batches.push(arr.slice(i, i + batchSize)); // slices array to 
  }
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: batchArray: batches = "+batches.length)
 
  return batches;
}


Sorry for the delay, and I appreciate the answer! Running into an issue with it though. I think you are on the right track with trying to limit the code and stop it from timing out, but I'm running into a new issue with this one. "ReferenceError: batchArray is not defined" tied to line 39, not running anything beyond it. I'm trying to look through the later part of the code to find a reason for it, but haven't been successful in getting the code past that point yet.

Argh. Mea culpa. ReferenceError: batchArray is not defined This is I because forgot to include the batchArray function in the answer - fixed that now. BTW, There are LOTS of Logger.log statements sprinkled through the code. They are handy for debugging/troubleshooting. But once the script is running as expected, you should comment out any unnecessary lines because they do slow down the code.
